# Swift If Statements

Tags: swift, if-statement

I have a registration view controller that 1) makes an empty textfield text red after the user has his the submit button and 2) shakes the empty textfield using a UIView.

```
// if registered button is clicked and textfields are empty
if usernameTxt.text!.isEmpty || passwordTxt.text!.isEmpty || emailTxt.text!.isEmpty || fullnameTxt.text!.isEmpty  {    

    // display red placeholders for empty textfields
    usernameTxt.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Username", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red])    
    passwordTxt.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Password", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red])    
    emailTxt.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Email", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red])  
    fullnameTxt.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Full Name", attributes:
            [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red])

}

// shake username textfield if it is empty
if usernameTxt.text == "" {
    usernameTxt.shake()
}

// shake password textfield if it is empty
if passwordTxt.text == "" {
    passwordTxt.shake()
}

// shake email textfield if it is empty
if emailTxt.text == "" {
    emailTxt.shake()
}

// shake fullname textfield if it is empty
if fullnameTxt.text == "" {
    fullnameTxt.shake()
}

} else {

    // remove keyboard
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

However, if the textfield is empty, it still executes the red placeholder text as well as the textfield shake BUT it also executes code after the " } else { "

Does anyone have any suggestion on re writing this code so that the code after the else isn't executed? Thanks in advance

Comment: Something is wrong with your code... the brackets don't line up. As it is, you aren't showing the first if statement that the else is attached to, so it is impossible to rewrite. If you want the else to execute only if the other fields aren't empty: put the if's within your first if that checks if any are empty, and the else should be attached to it's statement, which it currently isn't.

Comment: I just edited your if statements to add proper indentation. @EvanCarslake is correct - nothing aligns with the `else`. Are you missing a "top level" `if`? As it stands, the only thing that makes sense is to indent *everything* above the `else` another 4 spaces.

Comment: sorry I deleted some redundant code to make it shorter. And forgot to remove a bracket

Answer (score 1):

You need to chain you else condition on to the if statement. Currently you have them separated. For Exmaple:

```
if (condition) {

} else {

}
```

Else they are not part of the same evaluation. In summary, seems like you just have a syntax issue.

Cheers.